# Android Programming httpclient

Tags: android, textview, httpclient

I'm working with Eclipse (Android Developer Tools)
This page gives me two errors, could someone explain what's to do please?

thanks a lot!

```
package com.example.myproject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InternetTest extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_internet_test);

        // Internet test

        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://myurl.com/test.txt");

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

        BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

        InputStream is = buf.getContent();


        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line + "\n");
        }

        TextView.setText(total);

        // test done
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_internetseiten_test, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The errors:

"httpclient cannot be resolved"

"Cannot make a static reference to the none-static methode setText(CharSequence) from the type TextView"

I imported external jars ( these: http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi )

Thanks!

Comment: If you right-click on the error. What does it say? I'll bet it says 'import HttpClient', click on that.

Comment: for "Cannot make a static reference to the none-static methode setText(CharSequence) from the type TextView make an object of TextView probably intstance of TextView declared in layout file using findViewById(R.id.xxx),as setText is for object not Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is caused because you haven never specified what `httpClient` is.

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();
```

The second problem is because you are making a static call to a non-static function. You have to tell the system what TextView to set the text to. Not knowing it's name, I'll just show you roughly how it's done.

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.someTextBox)).setText(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize httpClient before using it..

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 1000 * 60);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 0);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
```

And get the text view from the layout and set it

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view)).setText(total);
```